# Vim is not creating .swp files

Tags: vim

I was working in vim and my OS(Mac OS X El Capitan) crashed.

I tried to recover from `.swp` files created by vim (usually). But, I noticed that vim is not creating them. I already setup swap/backup directories but not luck.

Btw: Im using this well-know vim config (https://github.com/amix/vimrc)

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue, IDK why but by default backups and swap mode are disabled if you use this well-know vim config ((https://github.com/amix/vimrc))

To fix it, just add these lines to your vim config file

```
set swapfile
set backup
```

Comment: FWIW the basic vimrc there has a section that turns this stuff off, with the comment "Turn backup off, since most stuff is in SVN, git et.c anyway...". So that is apparently the reason, as written by the author.

Comment: @DanLowe ah ok, but what about .swp, even if u are using git, if u pc crashed, u will lose all un-saved changes.

Comment: I don't agree with the author's logic... I'm just pointing out that is apparently the reason they turned those features off. Personally I use backup files in vim.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where Vim wasn't challenging me when I was editing a file twice.  It turned out that somewhere along the line I had an old version of that file's `.swp` file and it was creating a `.swo` file instead.  I exited Vim, removed the old `.swp` file and when I re-edited the file in question it created the swap file with the `.swp` extension.  If I tried to edit the file in another window it complained that a swap file already existed, as it should.

These alternative swap file names are discussed [here](http://ttm.github.io/research/2017/11/02/vim-swp-swo.html).